# Your Ruby version is 3.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a strange problem, I am using ruby on rails.

I hosted my server locally with rails. I stopped it and restarted it and it said: Your Ruby version is 3.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.2

I then changed the gemfile to: 3.2.0

and now it says: Your Ruby version is 3.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.2

I really don't know how this is happening, I feel like it's trolling me honestly

I've only tried changing the gemfile to use different versions of ruby, I don't know what else to do.

Here's a picture of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ98f.jpg

Update: I made a new rails app and noticed that it uses ruby "3.1.2" by default. The server ran using "rails s". I tried changing the gemfile to "3.2.0" and now I'm getting the same problem as before. I can't host the server on whatever version I use in my gemfile.

Comment: there are two places to change the ruby version in ruby on rails, first in Gemfile and you have to run bundle install to update Gemfile.lock, second there is a file called .ruby-version, change the version as well.

Comment: @BouaikLhoussaine there is a hell of a lot of other ways you can end up with an unexpected Ruby version. It can be specified through env variables, you could have the wrong version on your PATH - for example if you changed the shell ruby with RBenv or RVM.

Answer (score 0):

sry for taking up your time, but I fixed it by reinstalling ruby/ruby on rails